# ListView update doesn't update after new ListTile gets added as a children in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I have a simple flutter app which just shows the ListTiles of a ListView... This listView's children property is set to a list called "tiles"... **Whenever user presses the floating action button then then a new ListTiles object gets added to "tiles" and this is wrapped inside set state...** so I would expect the UI to update and show me new updated listView with more ListTiles... **but that doesn't happen...**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<ListTile> tiles = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('length of tiles: ${tiles.length}');  // prints the length of tiles correctly
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            tiles.add(ListTile(title: Text('Hello ${tiles.length+1}')));
          });
        },
      ),
      body: ListView(children: tiles),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You really want to use `ListView.builder` for these kind of things and replace list of widget with list of Strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @LonelyWolf said: You should use a `ListView.builder` and add Strings to your List instead of widgets

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<String> tiles = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('length of tiles: ${tiles.length}');  // prints the length of tiles correctly
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            tiles.add("${tiles.length+1}");
          });
        },
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: tiles.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index){
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('Hello ${tiles[index]}'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```